# Change text to inline TeX with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, math, mathjax

I use the regex

```
/\$([^$]*)\$/g
```

to replace text inside two $'s with latex.

In javascript, I use

```
text.replace(/\$([^$]*)\$/g, function (str, match) {
    return changeToTeX(match);
}
```

It works almost as it should, but, for instance, this text

> The price is between $400 and $500.

will be messed up because it thinks that it should convert `400 and` to latex since this text is between dollar signs.

Maybe it is not possible to fix. I have just checked math.stackexchange.com which supports the same behaviour with text inside dollar signs being replaced by latex, but here the same problem is occuring with all text between dollar signs being interpreted as latex.

Comment: Since you've tagged this with MathJax, note that MathJax's tex2jax preprocessor is more complex and also offers escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have numbers inside `$...$`, use

```
/\$(\d+)\$/g
```

where `\d+` matches 1 or more digit. The pattern inside can be enhanced to match any kind of numbers (see [*Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)).

To match anything but `$` and whitespace, use

```
/\$([^\s$]*)\$/g
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7oQ4rr/1)

Possibly, to only require word chars after the first `$` and before the last `$`, use

```
/\B\$\b([^$]*)\b\$\B/g
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7oQ4rr/2)

Comment: @Tushar: That is only if the numbers in `The price is between $400 and $500.` should be matched. I understand that there should be no match in this sentence.

Comment: It seems to work :) But if I write $ 2 + 2$ with a space in front or write $\frac{3}{4}$, it doesn't work any longer

Comment: Aha, so what are the specifications then? You know, a *regular* expression can only match *regular* text. Let me guess: there can be anything after the first `$` and there can be anything but space before the trailing `$`? And no `$` in between? Try [`/\$(?![^$]*\s\$)([^$]*)\$/`](https://regex101.com/r/7oQ4rr/3).